# Testing TLS certificate authentication in case of mismatched key/certificate

Tags: python, ssl, https, certificate, client-certificates

I have a web service which uses TLS client certificates for user authentication. Now I would like to write a full-stack test if the service implements ("is configured to do") certificate authentication correctly.

In particular I'm wondering if it is possible to encrypt a request with a key that does not match the presented client certificate.

Ideally the test would be written in Python but any other common language will do as well.

So my first attempt was by using Python's `requests` package:

```
requests.post(url, data=payload, cert=(cert_path, key_path), verify=False)
```

This works if the key matches the certificate but in case of a mismatch I just get

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [X509: KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH] key values mismatch (_ssl.c:2718)
```

which is a client side error so the request never hits the server (and hence does not test anything there).

So my question is: Is it actually possible to present a bad certificate or is that impossible by protocol design? Any hints how to implement such a test?

Comment: It is impossible to present a certificate unless you also have a correct private key for it, as you also have to present a digital signature created with that private key to prove you own the certificate. No SSL API I am aware of will permit it.

Answer (score 2):

In the TLS protocol it is possible to send a `CertificateVerify` message where the included signature does not match the certificate sent by the client. So it is not excluded by protocol design and it would be impossible to exclude it since the goal of this signature is to proof that the client has access to the private key matching the sent certificate.

But, by using `requests` you are doing tests at a very high level which actually tries to protect you from typical mistakes. If you want to do tests with invalid signatures etc you need to work at a lower level, for example by constructing your own TLS handshake using [scapy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scapy-ssl_tls). Note that you need to have deeper knowledge of how TLS works for doing such tests.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running HTTPS, the underlying SSL connection can't be completed with "bad" certificates if you've configured your server to reject them.

Since there is no SSL connection, you can't pass HTTP requests of any kind.

Which is the point of the design - to keep unwanted clients out entirely.